# Предлагаю добавить на StackOverflow в раздел Вопросы/Фильтр запоминание последних введенных меток

Tags: поддержка, предложение, метки, использование-метки

Если человек хочет ответить на вопросы, связанные, например, я языком программирования Java, то он должен перейти по пути:

`Вопросы->Фильтр->И ввести метку для поиска`

Однако, во-первых, некоторые метки длинные, например, [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [база-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)(тут еще и дефис), [регулярные выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f), а также веб-программирование, android-studio, многопоточность и так далее. При быстром их введение велика вероятность случайной опечатка, а при введении неверной метки пользователь получит ответ:

`Нет вопросов с меткой метка-с-опечаткой. Посмотрите список доступных меток для этого сайта.`

Причем введенная метка сотрется и придется вводить ее заново.

Во-вторых, допустим, я ответил на вопрос по Unity, затем нажал на `Вопросы` и чтобы перейти к вопросам о Unity, мне опять нужно вводить метку Unity.

Мое предложение:
Добавить запоминание хотя бы 3 последних введенных вариантов (как в поисковой строке любого поисковика). Нажимая на поле `Указанные ниже метки` вылезает выпадающее меню с 3 последними вариантами, при нажатии на один из которых вопросы сразу сортируются (как и при ручном введении метки). Причем запоминаются только верным метки, а с опечатками или несуществующий, на которые был получен ответ `такой метки не существует` запоминаться и показываться не будут, так как смысла в этом никакого нет.

Таким образом, нам не придется каждый раз вводить название метки для сортировки вопросов, а просто нажимать на первую строку выпадающего меню. Это гораздо быстрее, чем вводить длинные, сложные (за счет наличия дефисов, пробелов и самой длины) названия меток.

Как говорил один умный человек

```
Никогда не тратьте 6 минут на то, чтобы сделать что-то вручную, когда вы можете потратить 6 часов на то, чтобы автоматизировать это.
```

Comment: Вы наверно не знаете про существование `Пользовательские фильтры` и `Отслеживаемые метки`, ведь они делают почти то, что вы и предлагаете.

Comment: Хмм, а разве не достаточно просто клика по метке для отображения вопросов с ней?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ отслеживаемые метки - это не то, так как они просто подсвечивают вопросы по теме, а Пользовательский фильтр - это да, полезно, но разве это значит, что то, что я предлагаю - неверно? Кстати, не знаю почему минусы поставили. Нормальное предложение, над которым разработчики могут задуматься. Я думаю это несложно реализовать.

Comment: @V-Mor нет. Если зайти в раздел метки то Unity будет на 8 строке...

Comment: андроид-студио на 2 странице, а VisualStudio на третьей строке второй страницы

Comment: Ну, начнем с того, что минус не мой, а лично я считаю это предложение избыточным, ибо мне хватает того, что перечислил выше (и да, он не просто подсвечивает, а сохраняет то, что вы указали в фильтрах в удобный список, при помощи которого вы любой фильтр всегда можете применить). Ну и закончим тем, что все предложения тут ИМХО, бессмысленны, ибо мы все лишь пользователи движка SO, который разработан американской компанией и вот все предложения надо посылать на En.SO, а не сюда)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вы что, я не говорил, что минус лично ваш:) Пользовательские фильтры и отслеживаемые метки - это немного разные вещи. А разве разработчики русского Overflow не могут сделать что-то не так, как в оригинальном. Их руки же не связаны оригиналом, они же в конце концов не просто переводчики. Наши сайты имеют отличия, или все, что происходит на русском SO должно согласовываться с enSO? Я просто не знаю точно систему)

Comment: Ну а насчет избыточности... Не знаю... Мне кажется, что любая нормальная поисковая строка должна иметь способность запоминания хотя бы нескольких предыдущих поисковых запросов

Comment: Про то, как тут все устроено уже не ко мне. На сколько мне известно, движок один, у наших есть что-то по типу админки, где они могут включать/выключать/настраивать функции, ну и перевод полностью на сообществе, а вот все нововведения, это уже изменение основного движка, на котором сидит все SO и первыми они появляются на en.so, а уж затем выкатываются нам (например, темная тема, которая сейчас обкатывается там и до сих пор нету у нас). Так что не думаю, что вашу идею сможет кто либо реализовать. Единственное, у нас есть сотрудники из компании, но я не думаю, что они будут этим заниматься)

Answer (score 1):

Гораздо лучше было бы автодополнение меток, как это сделано при их написании у вопроса.

Comment: Но оно ведь есть. Когда начинаешь вводить название метки в фильтре, выпадает список вариантов.